# Is it really necessary to write the type definition in both the sig and struct part of a module to make it non abstract?

Tags: ocaml

This is a minor issue but annoying.

```
 module Example : sig
    type t = int
  end = struct
    type t = int
  end
```

I get that I have to include the type in the signature, otherwise it's abstract and hidden... that's fine. But is it necessary to write it out in the struct as well? In this case it's pretty trivial, but if I have a lot of large records or other complex types it gets annoying. I could just not include a sig at all, but I often want some publicly visible types but also some hidden properties.

As far as I can tell, nothing will compile if the struct doesn't exactly copy the type definition from the signature.. is there any way to tell it "Just copy what's in the signature", rather than actually having to copy and paste? If not... why not?

Comment: I know OCaml used to have a tool that would auto-generate a interface file from your source.

Comment: @G4143 They still do! `ocamlc -i file.ml` will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Well yes and no.

You can just write:

```
module Example =
 struct
  type t = int
 end
```

This code will work just as you'd expect.

However, and to our common sadness, there is no way to "import" your type definition from the signature. Copy-paste is your friend.

Side-note: As @G4143 mentioned in the comments, you can type `ocamlc -i myfile.ml` to print a complete type signature of your module, that can be useful too.